# How to see our Facebook Wall Posts and filter friends Wall Posts according to our requirements in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad

i am developing iPhone application using Facebook library where I want to access my Facebook wall posts and display in my application.
Also I want to see wall posts of only selected friends i.e. I want to implement filter in my application?

Comment: Can anyone please give me link for sample application on same.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Check out [facabook graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (You should create facebook account first)

You can fetch friends and wall posts by "/me/friends" and "/me/feed" graph API calls.

Use [facebook ios sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to perform graph API call requests.

Comment: To get friend's wall, use `/<friend_id>/feed`. You can get `<friend_id>` using `/me/friends`. You can also use `/me/home` to get list of news (your posts, friends posts, etc).

Comment: Thanks.. But I am unable to see all posts of the wall. it is showing me only few wall posts. What should i do now? Also do you have any sample application link on same.. Thanks again..

Comment: Do you get "paging" object in response? It should contain "next" and "prev" links.